# JSON zero value issue

Tags: iphone, json

I am using JSON web service. First i am saving the values on server then fetching same. The fields which i am leaving empty during inserting values are showing 0 values when i hit the API or url. And it is fetching in array showing in console but not showing on labels, buttons, etc. It is killing with error `[NSDecimalNumber length]`. I want to know what is wrong here, and  what those tags returns which are left empty during insertions. And how to detect that tags have zero value or null value. And how to deal with them.

Here i am posting the JSON

```
{
   "messageshow":[
      {
         "message_id":"502",
         "message":"http://flut.psites.info/api/messages/voice/1360100571.caff",
         "message_pic":"",
         "uid":"44",
         "created":"14 second ago",
         "username":"pari",
         "first_name":"pp",
         "last_name":"pp",
         "profile_pic":"http://flut.p-sites.info/api/uploads/13599968121.jpg",
         "tag_user":{
            "tags":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "boos_list":{
            "booslist":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "aplouds_list":{
            "aploudslist":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "total_comments":0,
         "total_boos":0,
         "total_applouds":0
      },
      {
         "message_id":"501",
         "message":"http://flut.psites.info/api/messages/voice/1360100045.caff",
         "message_pic":"",
         "uid":"44",
         "created":"9 minutes ago",
         "username":"pari",
         "first_name":"pp",
         "last_name":"pp",
         "profile_pic":"http://flut.psites.info/api/uploads/13599968121.jpg",
         "tag_user":{
            "tags":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "boos_list":{
            "booslist":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "aplouds_list":{
            "aploudslist":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "total_comments":0,
         "total_boos":0,
         "total_applouds":0
      },
      {
         "message_id":"500",
         "message":"http://flut.p.info/api/messages/voice/1360099970.caff",
         "message_pic":"",
         "uid":"44",
         "created":"10 minutes ago",
         "username":"pari",
         "first_name":"pp",
         "last_name":"pp",
         "profile_pic":"http://flutpsites.info/api/uploads/13599968121.jpg",
         "tag_user":{
            "tags":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "boos_list":{
            "booslist":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "aplouds_list":{
            "aploudslist":[
               {
                  "message":"false"
               }
            ]
         },
         "total_comments":0,
         "total_boos":0,
         "total_applouds":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I think its bcoz which value you are leave empty is int so its by default 0.

Answer (score 0):

First: What are you using to parse the received JSON data? `NSJSONSerialization`, `JSONKit`, ...?

Second: I guess that you try to call `-length` on a value from the parsed JSON data. But because that value is empty (0) it get's parsed into a `NSNumber` instead of a string. `NSNumber` doesn't implement a `-length` method and your app crashes.

You should return null or an empty string in your JSON for empty string values and not just `0`.

P.S.: Don't use `NSDecimalNumber`, but `NSNumber` instead. `NSDecimalNumber` is meant for performing calculations and not to wrap integers.